# Avoid certain parts being modulated by CanvasModulate in Godot 4.1

Tags: rendering, godot-4

I'd followed a tutorial on how to make a day and night cycle in Godot 4.1. Basically it consists on a [`CanvasModulate`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_canvasmodulate.html) node that changes color based on a gradient that imitates the different kinds of light color during the day and a `sin()` function. So far so good.

The problem is that my generic `Enemy` class has a [`Label`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_label.html) hidden on top of it that shows the damage received when they are hit. **This label is also getting modulated by the night and day cycle, and it shouldn't.**

I've tried playing with the `Z_index` of both, `Label` and `CanvasModulate`, but it doesn't seem to work as I expected: **everything gets modulated no matter the index.**

I've also tried to put in this label as a child of a [`CanvasLayer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_canvaslayer.html), and this as a child of the `Enemy` class, which works fine for the modulation aspect, but **the label gets rendered in a corner**, or in the middle if I enable `follow_viewport_enabled`. Also I get a bunch of errors about "*... was modified from inside an instance, but it has vanished*" when I instance `Enemy` subclasses.

Maybe my design is flawed and those labels belong to the GUI (which works fine because it's in its own `CanvasLayer` and doesn't "move"), although I find it more intuitive to be children of the enemy, so I don't need to pass positions from the game to the GUI and create new labels when enemies get hit.

Any words of wisdom would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the author of the tutorial told me, one way to avoid the modulation is adding a `CanvasItemMaterial` in the `Label`. In this `Material`, set the `Light Mode` to `Unshaded`. This works nice in my project.

Answer (score 3):

If the `Label` is temporary, then passing the position - as you have been trying to avoid - is the best solution.

If it must stay with the `Enemy`, and it is a `Node2D`... You could make the `Label` a child of another `Node2D` (somewhere it is unaffected) and use a `RemoteTransform2D`.

Another option - which I find simpler - is to make a `Control` with a script that lets me specify the `Node` it must follow, and then it can read its position in `_process` and position itself accordingly. Then the `Label` or whatever you need to display (e.g. a `ProgressBar`) can be a child of said `Control`.

*For this you might have to convert the position from the game world to the window, which I believe is `get_global_transform_with_canvas`.*